# Adjusting exposure of EXR file in video editing does not produce correctly exposed image

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, color-management

I am attempting to render an animation of a very bright scene (using Eevee). In order to obtain the look I want, I have turned the exposure down to -7.5 under the color management settings, which results in it appearing as I intend it in the viewport and render result. My complete color management settings in my scene are as follows:

- Display Device: sRGB
- View Transform: Filmic
- Look: Medium Low Contrast
- Exposure: -7.500
- Gamma: 1.000
- Sequencer: sRGB

[image: Render Preview and Desired Result]

Then in order to render the animation I exported the frames as OpenEXR files and added them as a frame sequence to a video editing project. Upon initially importing the frames, the image was completely blown out and overexposed, which wasn't entirely surprising given what I thought I knew about how EXR images work. However, trying to get back to the look I had in the viewport by turning the exposure down to -7.5 in the color management settings for the video editing project did not behave as expected. It instead dimmed the entire image as a whole, resulting in the blown out areas still being blown out but just now a dim gray instead.

[image: Overexposed Image in Frame Sequence]
[image: Attempted Exposure Compensation of Overexposed Image]

From what I understand, the EXR files store raw, linear color values that range from zero to infinity, ignoring any color management settings. I would expect that I could then just replicate my color management settings from my scene in the video editor to get the same look, but that's not working for the exposure. It almost seems like the values in the EXR file are being clamped at some point?

I'm guessing I'm missing some obvious step in either the rendering settings of my scene or the compositing settings of the video editor in order to get my desired behavior. I'm a complete novice with Blender and compositing as a whole so my fiddling with settings has been largely ineffective.

Comment: What video editor are you talking about? Are you editing the rendered EXRs in Blender? What precise steps lead to the problem? I cannot replicate the issue. EXRs work fine when imported to the compositor or to video sequencer as an image sequence.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I'm using Blender's video editing workspace to assemble the rendered frames into a video. The steps I followed were:
- Set up the scene
- Adjust the color management exposure down
- Specify output properties as OpenEXR RGBA Float (Full)
- Render animation frames to a folder
- Create new video editing project
- Add a frame sequence of the rendered frames
- Adjust the color management exposure down

Comment: The VSE is a completely broken mess with respect to pixel control. If you want a properly managed VSE, you'll have to advocate for it and shift the aimless boat floating adrift.

Comment: @troy_s are you trying to say that this is a bug? I'm not sure if I catch your drift.

Comment: I’m trying to say that the VSE is a catastrophic mess at this point, and should be removed. At some point, if the BI decides to give it a go, the thing needs to be redesigned from the ground up with management at the forefront. I’d not trust it for anything as the whole thing is a mishmash of legacy concepts.